# Converting a paragraph to hex notatation, then back to string

Tags: c#, hex

How would you convert a parapraph to hex notation, and then back again into its original string form?

(C#)

A side note:  would putting the string into hex format shrink it the most w/o getting into hardcore shrinking algo's?

Comment: Are you talking about base64?  I was going to post an answer, but on re-reading I'm not sure you know what you mean.  Can you give an example of a string you want to convert, and then an example of the same string converted?

Comment: Agreed with Adam -- I'm not sure the poster knows what he wants.  If you want to turn "Hello" into "48656C6C6F", that's pretty easy, but I don't think that's quite it.

Comment: I'm guessing homework assignment.

Answer (score 6):

What exactly do you mean by "hex notation"? That usually refers to encoding binary data, not text. You'd need to encode the text somehow (e.g. using UTF-8) and then encode the binary data as text by converting each byte to a pair of characters.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Hex
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string original = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

        byte[] binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original);
        string hex = BytesToHex(binary);
        Console.WriteLine("Hex: {0}", hex);
        byte[] backToBinary = HexToBytes(hex);

        string restored = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(backToBinary);
        Console.WriteLine("Restored: {0}", restored);
    }

    private static readonly char[] HexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();

    public static string BytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(data.Length*2);
        foreach(byte b in data)
        {
            builder.Append(HexChars[b >> 4]);
            builder.Append(HexChars[b & 0xf]);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] HexToBytes(string text)
    {
        if ((text.Length & 1) != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex: odd length");
        }
        byte[] ret = new byte[text.Length/2];
        for (int i=0; i < text.Length; i += 2)
        {
            ret[i/2] = (byte)(ParseNybble(text[i]) << 4 | ParseNybble(text[i+1]));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static int ParseNybble(char c)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            return c-'0';
        }
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        {
            return c-'A'+10;
        }
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        {
            return c-'A'+10;
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
    }
}
```

No, doing this would not shrink it at all. Quite the reverse - you'd end up with a lot more text! However, you could compress the binary form. In terms of representing arbitrary binary data as text, Base64 is more efficient than plain hex. Use [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) for the conversions.

Comment: amazing!  What does b >> 4 do? shifting?

Comment: Yes, it shifts the byte right, so you end up with a single nybble (0-15).

Comment: visually speaking, how does that look? isn't the value of the byte changing now?

Comment: The byte itself isn't changing - numbers don't actually change their values. It's computing the value of the byte shifted right. To put it another way, just think of that expression as "b/16".

Comment: Thanks Jon, this has helped me a lot too.  I've got to process some text that has been stored in a varchar field as Hex for some reason.  The weird things we encounter in day to day development, lol :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string ConvertToHex(string asciiString)
{
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in asciiString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Comment: yeah i should have.. though thats the first piece of C# i've written in a while.  Im a Python hacker :)

Answer (score 0):

While I can't help much on the C# implementation, I would highly recommend [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzw) as a simple-to-implement data compression algorithm for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer can be more quickly reached if we ask: what are you really trying to do?  Converting an ordinary string to a string of a hex representation seems like the wrong approach to anything, unless you are making a hexidecimal/encoding tutorial for the web.

Answer (score 0):

```
static byte[] HexToBinary(string s) {
  byte[] b = new byte[s.Length / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    b[i] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
  return b;
}
static string BinaryToHex(byte[] b) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b.Length * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(256 + b[i], 16).Substring(1, 2));
  return sb.ToString();
}
```